# How to Add Column Labels When Piping in R with dplyr and labelled?

Tags: r, dplyr, labelled

Is it possible to create column labels while piping in R with dplyr? E.g. something like:

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  some_lovely_function_for_labels(mpg = 'Miles per gallon')
```

Perhaps the solution could work for a list of variable-labels pairs.

I've explored the labelled package to no avail.

Comment: Are you looking for `rename` and `rename_with` of {dplyr} perhaps?

Comment: Something like that, but for variable labels rather than variable names. I know labels are not often used in R, but I have imported a dataset from SAS and would like to be able to manipulate what came in.

Comment: I see. AFAIK, R  has no concept of variable labels (beyond names), but see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347548/r-assign-variable-labels-of-data-frame-columns and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317041/how-to-get-variable-name-and-labels-from-sas7bdat-into-a-data-frame (or here for a GUI-orientated software with R under the hood: https://www.jamovi.org/)

Comment: `attr(df$col, "label") <-"my label"`  is how you set the label, I would also like to know how to do this as part of a dplyr pipe!

Answer (score 1):

Followed the link provided by [I_O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20513099/i-o) and learned about the package [Hmisc](https://rdrr.io/cran/Hmisc/man/Overview.html). The following seems to work:

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  Hmisc::upData(labels = c(mpg = 'Miles per gallon'))
```